# How do I add categories from another user in outllook 2003 to my list of categories in 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, contacts

I'm sharing a contact list with another user on the network, but I'm using outlook 2007 and the other user is using outlook 2003. The other user has assigned many different categories, but I do not get those categories added to the list of categories I can choose from when adding/editing contacts, I can see certain contacts have those categories. How do I add those categories so I can also add them? The shared contacts originate from the other user.

Thanks

Comment: Just the option in 2007 to select all contacts and then all categories -> add to master category list would do it, but it isn't there. The categories I had when moving from 2003 to 2007 do not seem to be in the master category list either.

Comment: If changing settings on our exchange server would do it, that's also an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook 2003 stores categories in the registry. Outlook 2007 stores them in a hidden folder in Outlook. There is no built-in means of copying them from 2003 to 2007. It is possible to do if you are comfortable scripting in Outlook.

You can also use a product such as [Category Manager 3.0](http://www.vboffice.net/product.html?id=2006063&cmd=detail&lang=en&pub=6) (30 days trial) to export and import categories for Outlook 2003 and 2007.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately not the answer I was hoping to get